# Angular2 route with parameter conflicts with another route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following component that simply acts as `router-outlet`

```
@Component({
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@Routes([
    {
        path: '',
        component: ItemListComponent,
    },
    {
        path: '/:id',
        component: ItemInfoComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/new',
        component: NewItemComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/:id/edit',
        component: ModifyItemComponent
    }
])
export class ItemComponent {}
```

It correctly routes to `ItemListComponent`, where I have a datatable with items. When I click on an item, it loads the `ItemInfoComponent` well. But when I want to go to the `new` or `edit` page, it doesn't work. The `/new` routing redirects to the `ItemInfoComponent`, the `/edit` routing does not work at all.
The tricky part is, that `ItemInfoComponent` is a non-terminal routing component that defines sub-routes as well:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: 'app/info/info.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
})
@Routes([
    {
        path: '/details',
        component: ItemDetailsComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/history',
        component: ItemHistoryComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/logs',
        component: ItemLogsComponent
    }
])
export class ItemInfoComponent implements OnActivate {
...
}
```

Also, the routing part in my `ItemListComponent` looks like this:

```
export class ItemListComponent extends ListComponent<Item> implements OnActivate {

    private currSegment: RouteSegment;

    constructor(
        private router: Router) {
    }

    routerOnActivate(curr: RouteSegment, prev: RouteSegment, currTree: RouteTree) {
        this.currSegment = curr;
    }

    gotoDetail(event: any) {
        var id = event.target.innerText;
        this.router.navigate([`./${id}`], this.currSegment);
    }

    gotoNewCashRegister(){
        this.router.navigate(['/new']);
    }

    gotoModify(event: any){
        this.router.navigate([`/${this.selectedItems[0].id }/edit`]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Eventually, yes, but it may be a little outdated by now. I'll copy in the solution, if you are still interested.